# Are "Apps for Office" being deprecated as an approach now by Microsoft?

Tags: office-web-apps, office-integration, office-dev-pnp

Are "Apps for Office" (Office Add-in) being deprecated as an approach now by Microsoft?

I know SharePoint apps have changed quite a bit to a REST Javascript Library in SEWP model now.

What is the current guidance on Apps for Office as we move to SharePoint 2016 and beyond?

thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Office Add-in is a latest technology to enhance functionality in office client applications. Unlike old COM and VSTO technologies which are being deprecated. You can find the current guidance on official Microsoft site https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins. Office Add-in is a correct technology to enhance office client applications with SharePoint 2016.